# Stuck at 640x480 after rebooting on Ubuntu 20.0.4.1 LTS

Tags: boot, nvidia, display-resolution

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system that I have been using with no problem for well over a year. I dual boot this computer between Linux and Windows. In case this information is useful the video card is an nVidia GTX-1070.

Today I rebooted from Linux into Windows and then back into Linux about an hour later. When my machine started it took longer than normal but eventually did bring me into a login window, however I'm stuck at 640x480. If I log in there are no other resolutions available. Also, when I shut down or restart the computer, about 8 times out of 10 it hangs and I have to hold the power button in.

If I boot into Windows everything works perfectly so it does not seem like a hardware problem.

I would really appreciate any pointers anyone could provide because I'm a bit desperate to get this working again, I spend most of my time in Linux and use it for work and really don't have time to do a clean reinstall right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the NVIDIA drivers into your Ubuntu?  If you didn't use the `graphics-drivers` PPA, the driver from NVIDIA themselves does not install a DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) driver that allows for carry over into the next kernel update.  There have been at least 2 kernel updates /  upgrades over the last couple of days.  5.4.0-58 was updated to 5.4.0-59 and if you had the HWE installed it was upgraded to 5.8.0-34.

Comment: Thank you. I discovered that if I boot into grub and select kernel version 5.4.0-59-generic that everything works fine. So you are almost certainly right that this was the result of a kernel upgrade to 5.8.0-34.

Comment: If the NVIDIA DKMS driver was installed it would have updated the driver into the 5.8.0-34 kernel as well.  When you are in the 5.4.0-59 kernel if you type in `dkms status` it should show you any drivers that are using DKMS.  If you don't see any, then the NVIDIA driver from the `graphics-drivers` PPA was not installed.

Comment: The easiest soulution will be to remove the 5.8 kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just experienced the same problem after upgrading to 5.8.0-36-generic this morning.

I installed the NVIDIA driver manually using the terminal some 5 months ago.

The quickest solution is so go to 'Software & Updates', click on 'Additional Drivers' and install the desired driver there.

(Can't say if this works for everybody)

Comment: Same solution worked for me just now.  Ubuntu software update did something to mess up the graphics.  NVIDIA graphics card was using some other driver.  Picked "nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)", click "Apply Changes".  Ubuntu prompts you to boot after install.  Graphics worked after reboot.